# d3 tooltip not showing up but seems to be working

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

My tooltip is not showing up when I hover over the data. Is it because it's hiding behind my heat map? I'm not sure what I need to do for it to show. I've played around with the opacity but nothing.

```
    // create a tooltip
      var tooltip = d3.select("#heatmap")
        .append("div")
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("background-color", "black")
        .style("border", "solid")
        .style("border-width", "2px")
        .style("border-radius", "5px")
        .style("padding", "5px")

    var mouseover = function(d) {
        tooltip.style("opacity", 1)
      }
      var mousemove = function(d) {
        tooltip
          .html("The exact value of<br>this cell is: " + d.value)
          .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+10) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
      }
      var mouseleave = function(d) {
        tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
      }

var heatmap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
        .data(selectCategory.values)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.States)  ; })

        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Year) ; })
        .attr("class", "hour bordered")
        .attr("width", 30)
        .attr("height", 30)
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.Value); })
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using SVG, you should be able to use your browser inspector (or download the SVG and open it in Inkscape) to see if your tooltip is being rendered above, below, or at all, within your SVG markup.

Comment: it looks like it's below it. how do I update the code so that it's within

Comment: Have you tried appending the tooltip after you have appended the svg? Also, I have never tried this, but can you use the [Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) css property?

Comment: I actually got it to come up but I'm not able to see the text just the box comes up

Comment: Does Inspector show that the correct HTML is inside the tooltip div when you hover? Also, are any exceptions coming up in the Inspector console when you hover?

Comment: There are no exceptions coming up

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to see if the correct HTML is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200426/discussion-between-mowglib-and-user300).

Comment: I encountered similar problem, mine was solved when I updated the style of tooltip position to absolute  
     .style("position", "absolute")